Azure Functions zip deployment
Trying to automate my deployments with powershell, because I have multiple endpoints.
I ended up building this ps1 file
param(
    [string]$subscriptionId,
    [string]$resourceGroup,
    [string[]]$functionAppNames,
    [bool]$build = $true,
    [bool]$deleteBuild = $true
)

clear

if ($build) {
    # # Build your NestJS app
    npm run build

    # Zip it up
    powershell Compress-Archive -Path .\dist\* -Update -DestinationPath dist.zip # slow...
    # & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -r "dist.zip" ".\dist\*"
}

# Login to Azure and set the subscription
az login
az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

# Publish to each function app
foreach ($functionAppName in $functionAppNames) {
    Write-Host "Deploying to function app: $functionAppName"

    az functionapp config appsettings set --name $functionAppName --resource-group $resourceGroup --settings "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true"
    az functionapp config appsettings set --name $functionAppName --resource-group $resourceGroup --settings "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1"

    # tried both with no success...
    az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g $resourceGroup -n $functionAppName --src .\dist.zip
    # Publish-AzWebapp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $functionAppName -ArchivePath .\dist.zip
}

if ($deleteBuild) {
    Remove-Item .\dist.zip
    Remove-Item .\dist\ -Recurse
}

But for some reason, after the deployment is finished, there are no functions in my Function App.
OS: Windows
Plan: Consumption
PS: If I do the deployment using Visual Code (ctrl + P and selecting the instance), everything's working fine. I want to replicate the same steps, but can't find a way to make it work.

AFAIK, there is no build command script for Azure Function that creates a dist folder. For Azure Function to work, you need to zip the whole project with all files.
This command worked for me, as I am deploying an HTTP trigger.
My directory:

Code :
Untitled1.ps1 :
param(
    [string]$subscriptionId= "<subscription_ID>",
    [string]$resourceGroup="<resourceGroup_Name>",
    [string[]]$functionAppNames="<functionApp_name>",
    [bool]$build = $true,
    [bool]$deleteBuild = $true
)

clear

if ($build) {
    npm install
    powershell Compress-Archive -Path .\* -Update -DestinationPath dist.zip  
}

az login
az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

foreach ($functionAppName in $functionAppNames) {
    Write-Host "Deploying to function app: $functionAppName"

    az functionapp config appsettings set --name $functionAppName --resource-group $resourceGroup --settings "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true"
    az functionapp config appsettings set --name $functionAppName --resource-group $resourceGroup --settings "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1"

    az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g $resourceGroup -n $functionAppName --src .\dist.zip
}
if ($deleteBuild) {
    Remove-Item .\dist.zip
    Remove-Item .\dist\ -Recurse
}

Output :

Azure Portal :
I was able to see my function in the Azure Function app.

